# Could not resolve com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Have you added `mavenCentral()` to repositories? Follow [This](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
```

at the top of your build.gradle file